# In how many different ways can a football fan enter a stadium by one gate and leave by a different gate if there are 15 gates in the stadium?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can a football fan enter a stadium by one gate and leave by a different gate if there are 15 gates in the stadium?

Comment: This is a [Multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) problem.

Answer (score 3):

The fan can enter through any one of 15 gates any leave through any one of the remaining 14 gates. So the total number of ways is $15 \cdot 14 =210$ ways.